# CSS select all elements except elements and children in a certain class

Tags: css

I'm trying to hide all elements except those within a "print" div. I'm not sure my syntax is correct:

```
@media print {
            body *:not(#printable *) {  display: none;      }  
}
```

Comment: `#printable` means the **id** `printable`. For a classname, use `.printable`.

Comment: could it be you are missing a comma. @media print {
            body *:not(#printable, *) {  display: none;      }  
}

Comment: I take it `#printable` is a direct child of the body tag?  Why don't you make it easier for yourself and wrap everything else in a `#screen` div, and then just hide #screen and show #printable in that media query.

Comment: @andi I think I'll have to do it that way, I'm a little disappointed I didn't learn a way to do it how I had intended though.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to print just **printable** right? If this so the solution is this:

```
@media print {
   * 
    {    
     display: none !important;
    }

   .printable
    {
     display: block !important;
    }
}
```

You hide all elements but not elements with printable class

Comment: This overrides all my printable child element's display styles.